# How to reciprocal this imaginary exponent?

Tags: complex-numbers

Assume $x\gt 0$, how does one simplify $$e^{(-x^2t)/i}\  ?$$

I don't understand how we could change the i under to the top so I could use Euler's formula

Comment: $\,\frac{1}{i}=-i\,$...of course, assuming you're talking of the imaghinary unit.

Comment: Since $\frac{1}{i} = -i$, your expression is equal to $e^{ix^2t}$

Comment: Damn it, and I just figured it out myself lol. Which is funny because I spent 20 minutes whether I should ask this or not and then comes up with a solution immediately I asked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that $-i^2 = 1$ implies that $-i = \frac{1}{i}.$ Then apply Euler's formula as you mention.

Answer (score 4):

$\frac{1}{i}=-i$. In general, $\frac{1}{a+bi}=\frac{a-bi}{a^2+b^2}$. You can probably figure out the rest.